# How to debug standalone code in asp.net web application (equivalent to a java main() method)

Tags: java, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm a java developer.
Need to write some components in .NET.

I've created an asp.NET web application (my component needs to be a service that is called in http).
question 1
Created an HttpHandler, that calls another class that does smething usual (lets say, iterate over a list).

I want to debug the method in the other class, using a Main method, (as i would've done in java/eclipse), but the only way visual studio 2010 lets me debug the code is as an http service.

Any way I could just debug a simple standalone code that is inside a web application?

thanks.